# Unexpected token with a return statement

Tags: javascript

not sure what is going on, however, i am trying to return a material ui component when i loop through the keys of an object, however, i keep getting `Unexpected token`

I have posted my code below, i am unsure why this error is triggering:

```
  renderTableRow(subheader) {
    const { data, multiHeaderBy } = this.props;
    data.map((subdata) => {
      if (subdata[multiHeaderBy] === subheader) {
        Object.keys(subdata).forEach(key => return <TableRowColumn>scsc</TableRowColumn>);
      }
      return null;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Try wrapping the JSX in `(..)` to distinguish it from the comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an explicit `return` statement in your arrow function, you have to put the function body in `{ }`:

```
    Object.keys(subdata).forEach(key => { return <TableRowColumn>scsc</TableRowColumn> });
```

The "simple" form of arrow functions without `{ }` requires that the function body be a single *expression*, and `return` is not part of the expression grammar; it's a statement type of its own. That's why it's an "unexpected token" — after the `=>`, the parser expects either `{` or a token that can start an expression.

Comment: I'm not a JSX person so I can't say whether simply removing the `return` keyword would also work; it might.